# adding a column to SQLite table in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I would like to add another column to a table in my existing SQLite database.

Is this possible, or is there something specific I need to do to upgrade it?

If so, how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 10):

Use the [ALTER TABLE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) command:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
    ADD COLUMN new_column;
```

Comment: Where to i implement this at? in the createDatabse method? where i initially create the database?

Comment: You just execute that command in sqlite, same as any other SQL query.

Comment: If you extend `SQLiteOpenHelper` then I would recommend to use  `onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)`.

Answer (score 5):

Consider using an ALTER TABLE script this guide should give you all you need, http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the alter table clause [See this](http://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sqlite.org%2Flang_altertable.html&rct=j&q=sqlite%20alter%20table&ei=eHcXTrLGFobi0QGDmcyXBQ&usg=AFQjCNEdGtPBJKnd5-WD6niEBbbgAvzIrQ&sig2=Dl8wiZ9ccDrObD3bP-2EUQ&cad=rja)

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to implement this?